# why do I keep getting 0 from the pid field of the return value of bpf_get_current_task()

Tags: linux, unix, kernel, ebpf

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from bcc import BPF

program = '''
#include <linux/sched.h>
int hello_world(void* ctx){
    struct task_struct* task;
    task = (struct task_struct*)bpf_get_current_task();
    if (task){
        pid_t pid;
        pid = task->pid;
        bpf_trace_printk("pid is %d\\n", pid);
    }
    return 0;
}
'''

p = BPF(text=program)
syscall = p.get_syscall_fnname("execve")
p.attach_kprobe(event=syscall, fn_name="hello_world")
p.trace_print()
```

I am new to ebpf, this is my hello world program, I tried to get the pid of the process calling execvp syscall, but everytime I got 0, is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: Why are you embedding a C program inside a Python program? Have you tried writing and compiling the C code without the involvement of Python?

Comment: @Kurtis Rader I am new to ebpf, just followed the steps in <<learning ebpf>> by Liz Rice

Comment: Fair enough, @SolskGaer. I love Python but it's inclusion raises the question of whether the problem lies with the Python ebpf binding rather than the C code that captures the data.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that code from books or blog posts may no longer work due to changes in the APIs or software versions. The document you referenced seems to be less than a year old so that is unlikely to be why you are having problems but still possible. It is also unclear what you mean by "followed the steps in...". Is the code you showed us literally from that book or is it something you wrote? Does any of the code from the book produce the expected results for you? Lastly, always tell us the versions of the relevant software you are using.

Comment: Do you get warnings/errors when you save the c-part to a file.c and compile it with `gcc file.c`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by changing `pid = task->pid` to `ebpf_probe_read_kernel(&pid, sizeof(pid), (void*)&(task->pid))`